# How to install the latest version of Carrierwave. Get's an year old version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I tried to install the version 1.0 as mentioned in the readme file :

`As of version 1.0.0, CarrierWave requires Rails 4.0 or higher and Ruby 2.0 or higher. If you're on Rails 3, you should use v0.10.0.`

Then it gives me an error saying `Could not find gem 'carrierwave (= 1.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine`

In the ruby gems site also we get the version 0.10.0 built an year ago! Is there a different way to get the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal, type `gem install carrierwave -v 1.0.0`
or whatever version you want, then run bundle.

Comment: It says `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'carrierwave' (= 1.0.0) in any repository`

Comment: type gem list in the terminal and what version or versions of carrier wave do you have on th elist?

Comment: it doesn't look like it is valid. I tried to install it as well and it's not there. I think you're best bet is to use 0.10.0. That's what I use with rails 4 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of carrierwave is listed here:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/version.rb

as of this writing it is listed as "0.10.0" NOT "1.0.0".
I suspect they are prepping for 1.0, but aren't there yet?

so try that instead...